# Error:Realm.h file not found

Tags: objective-c

I added the `realm framework` in my project.Then import `Realm/Realm.h` in `ViewController.h` file. Now it works properly But,after i close the project and again open this project then it is showing the error message like : `Realm/Realm.h file not found`.

Comment: Right click on your project name in Xcode after that click on show in finder and paste your framework here.

Answer (score 0):

In order to import `.h` files separately the best way to create `.pch` file and include all `import` file there so the files will became accessible inside the whole project from anywhere instead of importing separate.

follow steps to create `.pch`

1. Make new file: ⌘cmd + N.
2. iOS/Mac > Other > PCH File > YourProject-Prefix.pch.
3. Make sure you display "All" and not "Basic". ( ...
4. Project > Build Settings > Search: "Prefix Header".
5. Under "Apple LLVM 7.1" you will get the Prefix Header key. (Xcode 7.3.1)
6. Type file directory **or** $(SRCROOT)/projName/PrefixHeader.pch
7. Clean project: ⌘cmd + ⇧shift + K.
8. Build project: ⌘cmd + B.

Hope this helps alot.